# Is there a simple way to access a value in a Polars struct?

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

A basic use of value_counts in a DataFrame is to obtain the count of a specific value.

If I have a df such as:

```
DataFrame({"color": ["red", "blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue"]})
```

then if I want the count for color = 'red' in Pandas I could simply use:

```
df['color'].value_counts()['red']
```

which is clear and obvious.

In Polars, value_counts() produces a DF with a column of struct values:

```
┌─────────────┐
│ color       │
│ ---         │
│ struct[2]   │
╞═════════════╡
│ {"green",1} │
│ {"blue",3}  │
│ {"red",2}   │
└─────────────┘
```

which could be split into a DF with separate columns using

```
counts = df.select(pl.col("color").value_counts()).unnest('color')
```

and then the required value can be obtained using

```
counts.select(pl.col('count').filter(pl.col('color') == 'red')).item()
```

similarly `group_by('color').len()` could be used instead of value_counts

This all seems rather complicated for such a frequent requirement.
Is there a simpler way of extracting a single count value using Polars and more generally to access struct values.

Comment: You could simplify `df.select(pl.col("color").value_counts()).unnest('color')` to `df.get_column("color").value_counts()`.

Comment: A single count would also be the length? `len(df.filter(color='red'))` aka `.height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `unnest`, you can do

```py
df.select(pl.col("color").value_counts()).filter(
    pl.col("color").struct["color"] == "red"
).item()["count"]
```

which gives

```
2
```

There's tradeoffs - not having an Index opens up more doors for scalability, but admittedly some operations to become more verbose

Comment: Thanks. A good approach to this specific question and I appreciate your 'tradeoff' insight, Because of repeated use with different values, in the real case I wrote a function to convert the `value_counts` output into a Dictionary. More generally, I find polars `struct` somewhat cumbersome to work with,

Answer (score 1):

[`Expr.value_counts()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/version/0.18/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.value_counts.html) indeed produces Series of structs as a result. But if you want to just calculate amount of `red` values you could probably just [`filter()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html) first, calculate [`count()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.count.html), and then use [`item()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.item.html) to get a scalar value as a result:

```py
(
    df
    .filter(color == 'red')
    # or .filter(pl.col('color') == 'red')
    .count()
    .item()
)

2
```

If you need more than one value, then using [`group_by`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by.html) works well:

```py
(
    df
   .group_by("color")
   .agg(pl.len())
   .filter(pl.col("color").is_in(["red","blue"]))
)

┌───────┬─────┐
│ color ┆ len │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ u32 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ blue  ┆ 3   │
│ red   ┆ 2   │
└───────┴─────┘
```

Alternatively, you can use the fact that [`Series.value_counts()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.value_counts.html) returns DataFrame with 2 columns instead of Series of structs, then [`filter()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.filter.html) out results:

```py
(
    df["color"]
    .value_counts()
    .filter(color = "red")
    # or .filter(pl.col('color') == 'red')
)

┌───────┬───────┐
│ color ┆ count │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ red   ┆ 2     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first answer is a simple approach to this specific question but needs to use the expression `.filter(pl.col('color') == 'red')`

Comment: I've used shortcut `color = 'red'` but you can use `pl.col('color') == 'red'` instead